# Where to store password file for rundeck ssh login?

Tags: ssh, configuration, rundeck

**Rundeck SSH Using Password Authentication**

Rundeck has an option to ssh into nodes using password authentication. This requires adding to `/var/rundeck/projects/PROJECT_NAME/etc/resources.xml` the `ssh-authentication` and `ssh-password-storage-path` properties as follows:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <node ... ssh-authentication="password" ssh-password-storage-path="keys/node.password"/>
</project>
```

Rundeck tells me that the password storage path must begin with `keys/`. But the documentation does not tell what the directory `keys` is relative to. So my question is:

**What is the absolute path to the directory for storing the password file?**

There is no `keys` directory in my rundeck installation, and when I make a `keys` directory in `/etc/rundeck`, `/var/lib/rundeck` and `/var/rundeck`, it fails with the error:

> Failed to read SSH Password stored at path: keys/node.password: org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: Path does not exist: keys/node.password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SSH Password Storage](http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#ssh-password-storage)

> When connecting to the remote node, Rundeck will look for a property/attribute specifying the location of the password storage path, in this order, with the first match having precedence:
>
> - **Node level**: ssh-password-storage-path attribute on the Node. Applies >only to the target node.
> - **Project level**: project.ssh-password-storage-path property in project.properties. Applies to any project node by default.
> - **Rundeck level**: framework.ssh-password-storage-path property in framework.properties. Applies to all projects by default.

Answer (score 4):

Rundeck seems to store contents of key storage in `/var/lib/rundeck/var/storage/content/keys` and its meta data in `/var/lib/rundeck/var/storage/meta/keys`.

Comment: I don't have a "storage" directory. 

This should not be this difficult!

Comment: `/opt/rundeck/var/storage/content/`

this is where I have all config files too, like:

/opt/rundeck/server/config/rundeck-config.properties